# Comparing classes and do action / Comparer 2 classes et faire une action

Tags: jquery, filter, menu, compare

I need some help. I have a menu, with links that I used like filters, to hide and show some galeries, that are associated with them.
For exemple the link filter "Digital Painting" shows the galery "Digital Painting" since the galery "Traditional Painting" stays hide.

In my reasoning, I give the same classes to the link and the galery, who need to be linked together, for exemple the link filter "digital painting" and the galery "Digital Painting" have the same class "digital-painting".
So if the class link filter and the class of a galery coincide, I show the galery who had the same class of the link actually clicked on, and I hide the others galeries.

///// * Result of the code below : When I clic on the first link, all galeries are display, and if I clic on the second link, all galeries are hidden.

Do you know how ?

*-- French : J’ai un menu qui me sert de filtre, pour afficher et cacher des galeries différentes. J’ai donc mis la même classe aux éléments qui doivent être reliés. Dans mon raisonnement, si la classe de la galerie correspond à la classe du lien cliqué alors elle s’affiche sinon elle reste cachée.
Résultat du code ci-dessous : lorsque je clique sur le premier lien du menu toutes les galeries s’affichent, si je clique sur le second toutes les galeries se masquent :/*

**Code JS :**

```
//--- I get my link filter element
var menuLink = $('.pageInt-header').find('.menuFiltre').find("li");

//--- I get my galery element
var pageIntGalerie = $('.pageInt-galerie').find('.galerie-mod');


$(menuLink).click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    //my link has few classes so I get the one who interessed me
    var classLink = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    //my galery has few classes so I get the one who interessed me
    var classGalerie = $('.pageInt-galerie').find('.galerie-mod').attr('class').split(' ')[5];

    //if class link filter = class galery//
    if ( classLink == classGalerie ){
        $(pageIntGalerie).show();
    }else {
        $(pageIntGalerie).hide();
    }

});
```

**Code HTML**

Menu :

```
<nav>
     <..><li class="**charaDesign** class-2 class-3"><a></a></li>
         <li class="interface class-2 class-3"><a></a></li>
     </..>
</nav>
```

Galeries :

```
<div class="pageInt-galerie">
                  <div class="class-1 class-2 class-3 class-4 class-5 **charaDesign**"></div>
                  <div class="class-1 class-2 class-3 class-4 class-5 **interface**"></div>
             </div>
```

PS : Sorry for my english... And I work in Local, so I don't have link

Thank's for the help :)

Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't you ever rely on a class list and extract from it staticly like you do, because if you add a new class you code won't work anymore, i refactor you html to work with data-* attrs and link it to the id on the galleries.

```
<nav>
  <li data-id="gal1"><a href="#">test1</a></li>
  <li data-id="gal2"><a href="#">test2</a></li>
  <li data-id="gal3"><a href="#">test3</a></li>
</nav>

<hr/>

<div class="pageInt-galerie">
  <div id="gal1" class="galery">test1 description</div>
  <div id="gal2" class="galery">test2 description</div>
  <div id="gal3" class="galery">test3 description</div>
</div>
```

For the js part

```
// on load hide all galleries.
  $('.galery').hide();

  $('nav li').on('click', function(){
    // hide all gals on click
    $('.galery').hide();
   //loop through all gals
   const els =  $('.galery');
   els.map(g => {
     const {id} = els[g];
     //extract only the one we want and show it
     id === $(this).data('id') ? $(`#${id}`).show() : true
   });
 })
```

Live pen : https://codepen.io/sersif-samer/pen/abNrQEQ

Comment: Hello @Sersif Samir, Thank's a lot for your time and your answer :) Unfortunately I'm working on a Wordpress and I can't add an ID on my "li" menu. Your code should work on button !

I found the answer after all (I will edit the post) :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

```
var menuLink = $('.pageInt-header').find('.menuFiltre').find("li").children("a");
var pageIntGalerie = $('.pageInt-galerie').find('.galerie-mod');
    
        $(menuLink).click(function(e) {
    
            //on annule le comportement par défaut
            e.preventDefault();
    
            var classLink = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            $(pageIntGalerie).hide();
            $("#"+classLink).show();
    
        });
```